# How DataGrid is notified when item in the collection is changed?

Tags: wpf, data-binding, datagrid, observablecollection

I have two DataGrids bound to the same ObservableCollection property in my ViewModel.
When I **edit** an existing row in one DataGrid another gets updated after row is commited.

But how  it works? The NotifyCollectionChanged event is not raised on the underlying ObservableCollection. I have checked it by subscribing to the event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, you are modifying the properties of the item (entity) of the collection, not the collection itself.
Therefore, the CollectionChanged event is not raised.
To update properties in an entity, INotifyPropertyChanged must be implemented in it.
But if the change of properties happens ONLY through bindings, then even this is not necessary.
Bindings use PropertyDescriptor and other types of reflection in their work.
This allows bindings to "know" that a property has been changed by another binding.

If you speak Russian, read my article: https://www.cyberforum.ru/wpf-silverlight/thread2650880.html

Comment: And every book tells that binding works via INotifyPropertyChanged. I'm frustrated with how many things work not the way that is described in docs.

Comment: "binding works via INotifyPropertyChanged" is a little different.
Correctly "binding using  INotifyPropertyChanged".
This is one of the mechanisms used by bindings, but not the only one.
There are a lot of complications in how bindings work.
You will remember: for the path to the property, they just need to specify a string value.
And therefore, it is impossible to get the value of the property without reflection.